# OpenFileDialog alternatives

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using OpenFileDialog for Winform.  How do I use the OpenFileDialog alternatives to select the path to a file (the location of the file may be on another machine), and then save that path in some other place like a file.

Comment: What is your question and problem then? All I see are facts.

Comment: You can not get a location of a file with a browser. Only the filename by upload.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_file

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Select a file: <input type="file" name="img">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: He wants only the filename/location without upload. Thats not possible.

Comment: This is not what you need.I need to select the path to a file on 
another machine

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you want to select a filepath using C# and windows.forms OpenFileDialog and then save the path in a text file.

```
    OpenFileDialog openLogDialog;
    if (openLogDialog.ShowDialog(mywinform) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
      Stream stream = new FileStream("C:\\testfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
      StreamWriter streamw = new StreamWriter(stream);
      streamw.WriteLine(openLogDialog.FileName);
      loadNewLogFile(openLogDialog.FileName);
      streamw.Close();
      stream.Close();
    }
```

The OpenFileDialog can select files on other computers over windows shares.